# Converting Ubuntu 18.04 from interfaces to netplan for network configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, ubuntu-18.04, netplan

An old employee at my place of work set up a Ubuntu 18.04 server instance to use the /etc/network/interfaces file for network configuration.  This has been causing some issues and I would like to revert back to using the /etc/netplan/*.yaml file approach instead.

I did some research on converting from netplan to interfaces, and it looks like some packages were installed to switch over.  However I would like to move back to the original configuration using the .yaml file for my network configuration.

How can I successfully convert back to using netplan?  I know how to set the .yaml file up correctly, however it is switching the server back to use this configuration instead of the the /etc/network/interfaces file that I am having trouble with.

Thank you very much.  Please let me know if you need any additional information and I will be happy to assist.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that I was able to comment out the contents of my /etc/network/interfaces file, configure my .yaml file with the correct network information, and then perform the following command:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

After doing so it pulled the network config from my .yaml file and everything appears to be functioning correctly.  Is there anything else that I should be worried about?

I performed a reboot to be safe and it retained the IP that I set up in my .yaml file.